# How To access properties in velocity Templete?

Tags: ant, properties, velocity

I have an properties file in one location (/home/XXXX) and want one of its property acessed in velocity templete in location (/irb/dev4/ccm_wa/cb532/RBAPI-XXX/RBAPI/BA/tools/src/com/gen/tools/build/j2ee/ejb). how do we access them??

I need the below foreach loop to be executed only if the above accessed property returns true

```
#if( **PROPERTY IS TRUE** )
#foreach ($databaseGroup in ${root.getAllDatabaseGroups().values()})
#foreach ($index in ${databaseGroup.getIndices()})
      <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>${databaseGroup.getResRefPrefix()}${databaseGroup.getTxDs(${index})}</res-ref-name>
        <resource-name>${databaseGroup.getResRefPrefix()}${databaseGroup.getTxDs(${index})}</resource-name>
      </resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Template class read the properties file into an `Properties` object and put this to the context. i would suggest [Apache Commons PropertiesyConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html) for that:

```
PropertiesConfiguration props = new PropertiesConfiguration("/home/XXXX");
contxt.put("props", props);
```

in your template file you can now check your properties:

```
#if($props.getBoolean(propertyName))
```